# Unity built-in Json not serializing object's public properties

Tags: json, unity-game-engine

Hey I'm trying to use the [Unity Json Utility (UnityEngine.JsonUtility)](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JSONSerialization.html) that comes built into the UnityEngine library to serialise a pretty simple object with a single public string field.

My code using the library is pretty straightforward:

```
var logDTO = new LogDTO();
logDTO.Message = "Unity speaks too!";
var obj = JsonUtility.ToJson(logDTO);
```

And my object is about as simple as it gets:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class LogDTO {
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

This is the json result.

> Expected: `{ Message : "Unity speaks too!" }`
>
> Actual: `{}`

You can see the whole thing in the following screenshot:

[image: Simple object not serializing]

Other Json libraries like JsonFX work as expected, but for some reason JsonUtility doesn't. Anyone come across this or see what I'm doing wrong with here?

Comment: IT can't serialize properties.  Remove `{ get; set; }`. See the troubleshooting section from the duplicate for more reason you might get an empty json.

Comment: Thanks @Programmer. Care to turn that into a post so that I can mark it as a solution?